# 45 years, on pension and thinking about getting job inside IT industry after really very long time mental illness - 13 years gap?

Tags: job-search

I'm 45 years old, I have never worked inside IT professionally, but I have IT education from Denmark which is something close to Bachelor (Danish name for education is Datamatiker - translated to English as  Datamatician, which takes 2 and half years).

Positive thing about my situation is that my health is much better. Negative and painful thing for me is that I feel that I am wasting my life sitting alone home doing nothing and I wish to work inside IT, but since I've come to Denmark I only worked few factory dead end jobs and took my education at age 32.

Since then my life fell apart and here I am 13 years later. At school we worked mostly with Java doing small programming exercises every day, and my biggest single program was around 1000 line Java GUI code, which is really small.  I've enjoyed pair programming, had stamina while searching for bugs in my code, was willing to help others with bugs in their code etc. Unfortunately for me lot of things changed in Java field since I have graduated from my school 2002.

When I read job ads (Like - We are looking for best Java programmer in world ) I'm scared to death by requirements for prospective candidates. Is this really hopeless situation?

Comment: What does it hurt to apply.   Really the add is "We are looking for best Java programmer in world".

Comment: I would suggest taking up training. Many online sites available. I am currently myself taking training from teamtreehouse.com. You can take a free trial and check if it works for you or from some other site. After you have spent 3-4 months on training , while simultaneously working on something at home, you can be ready to take on small projects or maybe work at a small place with low wages. Only when you get professional after 2-3 years can you hope to make good money. Think about it and take action. Of course it is difficult and you will go through a lot of struggle. Good luck.

Comment: 13 year gap is too big, take a course

Comment: Job ads are ridiculous. Back on 2006 when I was last looking for a job I saw an ad for someone with 10 years of .net experience. (.Net was, of course, released in 2002 :-). Look - just apply. Apply for anything. What's the worst thing that can happen? In this case, the worst thing they can do is ignore you. OK, so, no loss. Just apply.

Comment: @BobJarvis I think the people writing ads take "Ten years experience" and "Knowledge of language/framework X" to mean "Ten years experience of X", even if it is impossible.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest doing two things in parallel:

1. Go ahead with applications. At a minimum, you will get practice filling in application forms, and possibly interviewing.
2. Join a Java-based open source project. You will be doing something useful, bringing your Java skills up to date, building a portfolio of code you have written to show prospective employers, getting practice on larger programs, and building a professional network.

Comment: I fear opensource development is complex even for java developers with no gap.

Comment: @NiceGuy I am recommending it precisely because it is difficult, and therefore a good way of building and demonstrating skills the OP would need for a demanding job.